# Dynamically Setting Type of New Instance

Tags: c#, interface

I have an issue where I'm creating a new child in the exact same manner, for different child types. I'm not able to reuse the methods I call on it because I don't know how to dynamically set the type of the new instance.

```
if (radioSomeType.Checked)
{
    SomeType child = new SomeType();
    child.MdiParent = parent;
    child.Open();
}
else if(radioSomeOTherType.Checked)
{
    SomeOtherType child = new SomeOTherType();
    child.MdiParent = parent;
    child.Open();
}
```

I set some other properties and call some other methods within this piece as well, but I've removed them in this example.

I know how to use interfaces, but I'm not sure how to set the type initially for the instance.

I want to reduce duplication, and do something like this:

```
if (radioSomeType.Checked)
{
    SomeType child = new SomeType();
}
else if(radioSomeOTherType.Checked)
{
    SomeOtherType child = new SomeOTherType();
}
child.MdiParent = parent;
child.Open();
```

My issue is that even when I try to use interfaces, I still need to create the instance somehow within that conditional (which is what I would expect).

Comment: You shouldn't create the obect within the conditional, check out the factory pattern: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx

Comment: @ChrisHardie I see your point, but the factory pattern is not useful in this instance. I'm creating MDI children - there's no scenario in which at least one radio button is selected.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. You would pass the value of the radio button that is checked to the factory, and the factory would determine which object to pass back. It relieves your calling code from the responsibility of determining which object to create. If you have many radio buttons, a factory would clean things up nicely.

Comment: @ChrisHardie The factory pattern in most cases does that exactly, i.e. create different objects inside conditional branches - even the code you've referenced does that precisely. While I do believe the factory pattern has it's applications, I don't believe hiding the simple conditional flow as in this example is one of the valid ones.

Comment: @ChrisHardie: My point is that the factory code to create new instances performs the exact same logic. I think it's overkill to implement the factory pattern for this one occurrence (I wouldn't use it anywhere else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is something like the code below, where `ISomeType` is an interface that both `SomeType` and `SomeOtherType` implement.

The issue with your original code is that you declared the child variable inside of each `if` statement, so it is not available to any code outside of that block.

```
ISomeType child;
if (radioSomeType.Checked)
{
    child = new SomeType();
}
else if(radioSomeOTherType.Checked)
{
    child = new SomeOTherType();
}
child.MdiParent = parent;
child.Open();
```

Comment: I agree, this sounds about right. I thought I already tried this but I may be wrong. I'll test it and accept it if this is fine.

Comment: Works perfect. I moved the `Form` methods into my interface (which was already implemented on both of these forms).